# Single error popup during multiple async call in WPF MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, error-handling, async-await

We have MVVM based WPF desktop application where we use async WCF service calls.

We have a screen where it loads the following details:

1. User details
2. Recent orders placed
3. Recent orders Approved

When the client is not able to connect to the server (Ex: Web service not working or IIS site stopped), we get communication exception alert.

Since there are multiple parallel calls, we will get Communication Exception multiple times whereas we want to show alert only one time.

We are using Task.Run() so all calls are running on different threads.

**Note: There is 1 view, viewmodel and separate async WCF call for each of the above points and it is not possible to merge them into a single page and then make a synchronous call.**

Any idea how this can be handled?

Let me know in case further details are required.

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue?

Comment: I am trying to create an example with minimal details as the project is Huge it is taking some time. I will provide minimal code as soon as possible